# sqlite database sum values of the column

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I want sum values of the column, but I want to summarize the values ​​by skipping the first value and starting to summarize the second in a row. My code

```
 public  int sumColum(){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor result = db.rawQuery("select sum(PRICE) from wedding_table", null);

    if(result.moveToNext())
        return result.getInt(0);

    return  0;
}
```

Comment: And how to determine the first record?

Comment: Sample data and desired results might help clarify what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

SQL tables represent *unordered* sets, so there is no first price, unless another column specifies the ordering.

If you mean the highest or lowest price, then it is pretty easy -- assuming there are no duplicates:

```
select sum(PRICE) - min(price)
from wedding_table;
```

Comment: I want to summarize the second, third, fourth and so on to the last value in the column